# Set window scroll position to compensate for elements being removed from webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have a collection of react components that are rendered in react-stack-grid. As the user scrolls down the collection is populated using react-infinite-scroll-component, to limit the number of items in the collection I remove items from the list of components being rendered but when I do this the scroll position needs to be updated and move to compensate for the new elements.

Like so:

```
if (currentMediaItems.length > 40) {
    currentMediaItems = currentMediaItems.splice(currentMediaItems.length - 40);
}

return <div style={style} >
    <InfiniteScroll
        next={this.fetchData.bind(this)}
        hasMore={true}>
        <StackGrid monitorImagesLoaded={true} gridRef={grid => this.grid = grid} columnWidth={this.props.columnwidth}>
            {currentMediaItems}
        </StackGrid>
    </InfiniteScroll>
</div>;
```

When InfiniteScroll hits 'next' more items are loaded and the scrollbar position is adjusted to compensate so the window remains fixed in its current position.

However if I have more than 40 items to render and decide to remove all elements except the last 40 the scrollbar is not offset to keep the window fixed in the same relative position and instead stays at the bottom of the window.

How can I calculate the correct y scroll position based on the number of removed elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain JavaScript to set the window position:

```
window.scollTo(offsetX, offsetY);
```

Try to calculate the element height * element count and remove it from the current scroll offset.

You should also check out [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized). This is ideal for a use case like yours to enable performant lists with a lot of items.